How can I create a screen for a large picture window?
I have a triple pane slide window, three of them in fact, and I need to make new screens for them. The two side ones will be easy, but the big one in the middle is going to be an issue. It will be 50”w x 57”h, and the widest screen material at the big box store is only 48”. Is there a way to splice two screens together to span a larger frame, or am I going to have to special-order wider material?
I just finished doing the two side windows and discovered that a cross-brace is required to keep the sides from bowing in. Does anyone know of a source of “frame” pieces, or perhaps screen frames with two spline grooves? That would solve the width issue as well.


Won't the frame add to the dimension? 48" + 1" + 1" ?

No, because you have to have enough overlap to be able to stuff the material into the spline groove. The manufacturer recommends a minimum 5/8" overlap on all sides, which matches the width of the frame.

Why would the middle need a screen? Does it open somehow? I'd expect screens for the flankers with brush seals to the interior frame. The picture pane should remain clear for better visibility.

@isherwood - The screen was for thermal blocking and reducing brightness, not keeping bugs out. No the center panel did not open.

I found some wider material on Amazon, even thought it doesn't have the same "solar shade" weave. It should be close, though.
